# Thread.sleep( ) with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Espresso claims that there is no need for `Thread.sleep()` but my code doesn't work unless I include it. I am connecting to an IP and, while connecting, a progress dialog is shown. I need a `Thread.sleep()` call to wait for the dialog to dismiss. This is my test code where I use it:

```
    IP.enterIP(); // fills out an IP dialog (this is done with espresso)

    //progress dialog is now shown
    Thread.sleep(1500);

    onView(withId(R.id.button).perform(click());
```

I have tried this code without the `Thread.sleep()` call but it says `R.id.Button` doesn't exist. The only way I can get it to work is with the `Thread.sleep()` call.

Also, I have tried replacing `Thread.sleep()` with things like `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()` and still no luck.

Is this the only way to do this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: is it possible for you to put unwanted While loop anyway u want blocking call.

Comment: ok.. let me explain. 2 suggestions for you 1st)Implement something like call-back kind of mechanism. on-connection-establish call one method and show the view . 2nd) you want to create the delay in between  IP.enterIP(); and onView(....) so you can put the while loop  which will create the simillar kind of delay to call onview(..) ... but i feel if possible please prefer option No 1.(creating the call-back mechanism)...

Comment: @kedark Yeah that is an option, but is that Espresso's solution?

Comment: There are unanswered comments in your question, could you answer them?

Comment: @Bolhoso, what question?

Comment: @Binghammer this one. I've asked "Do you do something out of the UI thread or AsyncTasks?". This will guide troubleshooting the test's behavior

Comment: I have many threads and async tasks.

Comment: Im surprised Thread.sleep() works for you....I get this error when the sleep is done:

`NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?`

Comment: Hi Binghammer...are you still using the selected answer?  Or did you go with a different approach?  AsyncTasks?  IdlingResource?

Comment: Use this below single line of code for dealy any Test Espresso test case:

SystemClock.sleep(1000); // 1 Second

Comment: Adding an artificial delay in such cases should be considered a bad practice. [Check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259273/7201671)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

On my mind correct approach will be:

```
/** Perform action of waiting for a specific view id. */
public static ViewAction waitId(final int viewId, final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for a specific view with id <" + viewId + "> during " + millis + " millis.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + millis;
            final Matcher<View> viewMatcher = withId(viewId);

            do {
                for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    // found view with required ID
                    if (viewMatcher.matches(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

And then pattern of usage will be:

```
// wait during 15 seconds for a view
onView(isRoot()).perform(waitId(R.id.dialogEditor, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15)));
```

Comment: Thanks Alex,  why did you choose this option over IdlingResource or AsyncTasks?

Comment: This is workaround approach, in most cases Espresso doing the job without any problems and special 'wait code'. I actually try several different ways, and think that this is one is the most matching Espresso architecture/design.

Comment: @AlexK this made my day mate!

Comment: for me, it fails for api <= 19, at line throw new PerformException.Builder()

Comment: It's not running, `Matcher` import is not working for me. Any help with that? I tried org.hamcrest.Matcher but it just doesn't exist

Comment: use static import for Matcher methods. Code is working fine, You just should confirm that all dependencies are included: Hamcrest + Espresso 

And if it not working right now for you than double check the versions of the dependencies.

Comment: I hope you understand that its a sample, you can copy/paste and modify for own needs. Its completely yours responsibility to use it properly in own business needs, not mine.

Comment: Idling Resources is a new thing. Post was originally written 2 years ago. So For espresso library version that were available 2 years ago it was and OK solution and based on internal logic of Espresso lib.

Comment: Should work. Can you provide the line of call? Potentially it may stay in "endless" loop only if during the call used the wrong timeout value. For example minutes instead of milliseconds...

Comment: I am using record espresso test feature, the code get's generated on it's own, but i am still facing NoMatchingViewException...anybody has any idea regarding how to fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: @AlexK have you used this code in real life scenario? This bit of code doesn't work for me because when perform is being called view that I'm looking for isn't yet in the view hierarchy, so it always throws timeout exception. Perform method doesn't respond to newest views on the screen. The view is clearly displayed but your method doesn't see it

Comment: I'm having the same problem like @MTomczyński. Most of the times it works fine, but in some scenarios the new view elements or not passed in the View parameter, so it is not able to wait for the view even that it is clearly visible on the device. Otherwise it works fine so far!

Comment: `onView(isRoot())` is critical for code. 

If view visible on the device screen, but it cannot be catched by a test, than highly possible that selected a wrong view in `onView(...)` call.

@MTomczyński @bsautermeister

Comment: in addition, in case of an error if you want to have the name of the id you're waiting for you might want to use this:
```getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources().getResourceName(viewId)```

Comment: @AlexK: however, you are searching the element in its root, but if you want to search for an element which is in root, but the root is in the next screen(activity), your element won't be found anymore.

Example: Lets say we have a LoginActivity -> input credentials and hit login button. I want to wait for the next activity(HomeActivity) to be displayed. In this case, isRoot in your method will know only for LoginActivity.

Comment: To solve this case when the element is in another activity, the solution in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327230/2871861 worked for me.

Comment: For some reason none of these work for me, they all cause the test to just run/hang/spin forever. I have tried different variations of this, Thread.sleep, Systemclock.sleep etc all of them cause the test to just hang and spin forever.

Answer (score 62):

Thanks to AlexK for his awesome answer. There are cases that you need to make some delay in code. It is not necessarily waiting for server response but might be waiting for animation to get done. I personally have problem with Espresso idolingResources (I think we are writing many lines of code for a simple thing) so I changed the way AlexK was doing into following code:

```
/**
 * Perform action of waiting for a specific time.
 */
public static ViewAction waitFor(final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Wait for " + millis + " milliseconds.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(millis);
        }
    };
}
```

So you can create a `Delay` class and put this method in it in order to access it easily.
You can use it in your Test class same way: `onView(isRoot()).perform(waitFor(5000));`

Comment: the perform method can even be simplified with one line like this: uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(millis);

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that :thumbs_up @YairKukielka

Comment: Yikes for the busy wait.

Comment: Awesome. I was searching for that for ages. +1 for a simple solution for waiting problems.

Comment: Much much better way to add delay instead of using `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: This is fine but it has a limitation if it's chained to another call, like `onData(anything()).atPosition(1).perform(click()).perform(waitFor(2000));` : If your UI test moves to a different Activity/screen, then the `waitFor()` part will fail with `"androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching ..."`.  However, if `waitFor()` is called independently afterwards, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't see how calling this `ViewAction` is different to calling `SystemClock.sleep(millis)`. Both wait a fixed number of milliseconds before returning. I would strongly suggest defining your `ViewAction` classes to wait on a particular condition (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563297/1071320) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64497518/1071320)) so they return faster in most cases and only wait up to the maximum number of milliseconds in the case of error.

Answer (score 25):

I stumbled upon this thread when looking for an answer to a similar problem where I was waiting for a server response and changing visibility of elements based on response.

Whilst the solution above definitely helped, I eventually found [this excellent example from chiuki](https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/blob/a70a343862a4199804f6fdffd9173cd453bb8d11/idling-resource-elapsed-time/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sqisland/espresso/idling_resource/elapsed_time/MainActivityTest.java) and now use that approach as my go-to whenever I'm waiting for actions to occur during app idle periods.

I've added [ElapsedTimeIdlingResource()](https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/blob/a70a343862a4199804f6fdffd9173cd453bb8d11/idling-resource-elapsed-time/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sqisland/espresso/idling_resource/elapsed_time/ElapsedTimeIdlingResource.java) to my own utilities class, can now effectively use that as an Espresso-proper alternative, and now usage is nice and clean:

```
// Make sure Espresso does not time out
IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// Now we wait
IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime);
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);

// Stop and verify
onView(withId(R.id.toggle_button))
    .check(matches(withText(R.string.stop)))
    .perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.result))
    .check(matches(withText(success ? R.string.success: R.string.failure)));

// Clean up
Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
```

Comment: I get a  `I/TestRunner: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr.x.app.y.testtools.ElapsedTimeIdlingResource`error. Any idea. I use Proguard but with disable obfuscation.

Comment: Try adding a `-keep` statement for classes that are not being found to make sure that ProGuard isn't removing them as unnecessary. More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#keep-code

Comment: I post a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-with-espresso-and-proguard. The class is in the seed.txt and mapping.txt

Comment: If you need to change the idling policies, you're probably not implementing idling resources correctly. In the long run it's much better to invest time in fixing that. This method will eventually lead to slow and flaky tests. Check out https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/

Comment: You're quite right. This answer's over a year old, and since then the behaviour of idling resources has improved such that the same use case that I used the above code for now works out of the box, properly detecting the mocked API client - we no longer use the above ElapsedTimeIdlingResource in our instrumented tests for that reason. (You could also of course Rx all the things, which negates the need to hack in a waiting period). That said, the Google way of doing things isn't always the best: http://www.philosophicalhacker.com/post/psa-dont-use-esprsso-idling-resources-like-this/.

Answer (score 20):

I think it's more easy to add this line:

```
SystemClock.sleep(1500);
```

Waits a given number of milliseconds (of uptimeMillis) before returning. Similar to sleep(long), but does not throw InterruptedException; interrupt() events are deferred until the next interruptible operation. Does not return until at least the specified number of milliseconds has elapsed.

Comment: Expresso is to avoid these hardcoded sleep that causes flaky tests. if this is the case I can as well go for blackbox tools like appium

Comment: More about Espresso not recommending "sleep": https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource#identify-when-needed I'll start testing with it though, and then refactor.

Comment: The funny part is that I tried all the hard solutions first, and this is the one that worked jajajaja

Answer (score 13):

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327230/1015595) but uses a timeout instead of attempts and can be chained with other ViewInteractions:

```
/**
 * Wait for view to be visible
 */
fun ViewInteraction.waitUntilVisible(timeout: Long): ViewInteraction {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val endTime = startTime + timeout

    do {
        try {
            check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            return this
        } catch (e: AssertionFailedError) {
            Thread.sleep(50)
        }
    } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)

    throw TimeoutException()
}
```

Usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.whatever))
    .waitUntilVisible(5000)
    .perform(click())
```

Comment: I used this approach, but it didn't exactly work for me. I had to catch AssertionFailedError instead of NoMatchingViewException. With that change, it works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

You can just use Barista methods:

`BaristaSleepActions.sleep(2000);`

`BaristaSleepActions.sleep(2, SECONDS);`

Barista is a library that wraps Espresso to avoid adding all the code needed by the accepted answer. And here's a link!  https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista

Comment: I don't get the difference between this and just doing a thread sleep

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember in which video from Google a guy said that we should use this way to do a sleep instead of making a common `Thread.sleep()`. Sorry! It was in some of the first videos Google made about Espresso but I don't remember which one... it was some years ago. Sorry! :·)

Oh! Edit! I put the link to the video in the PR I opened three years ago. Check it out! https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista/pull/19

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to coding and Espresso, so while I know the good and reasonable solution is to use idling, I'm not yet intelligent enough to do that.

Until I become more knowledgeable, I still need my tests to somehow run though, so for now I'm using this dirty solution which makes a number of attempts at finding an element, stops if it finds it and if not, briefly sleeps and starts again until it reach the max nr of attempts (the highest number of attempts so far has been around 150).

```
private static boolean waitForElementUntilDisplayed(ViewInteraction element) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < ATTEMPTS) {
        try {
            element.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WAITING_TIME);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm using this in all the methods that are finding elements by ID, text, parent etc:

```
static ViewInteraction findById(int itemId) {
    ViewInteraction element = onView(withId(itemId));
    waitForElementUntilDisplayed(element);
    return element;
}
```

Comment: in your example, the ```findById(int itemId)``` method will return an element(which could be NULL) whether the ```waitForElementUntilDisplayed(element);``` returns true or false....so, that's not ok

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say this is the best solution in my opinion. `IdlingResource`s aren't enough for me due to the 5-second polling rate granularity (way too big for my use case). The accepted answer doesn't work for me either (explanation of why is already included in that answer's long comment feed). Thanks for this! I took your idea and made my own solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution that worked for me too, when wanting to wait for elements that are not in the current activity.

Comment: For me doesn't work, even with try-catch block the test showed failure (because any exception, prevents the test results ok). For me, I combine the recursive approach with Thread Sleep and withFailureHandler, which works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Espresso is built to avoid sleep() calls in the tests. Your test should not open a dialog to enter an IP, that should be the tested activity's responsability.

On the other hand, your UI test should:

- Wait for the IP dialog to appear
- Fill in the IP address and click enter
- Wait for your button to appear and click it

The test should look something like this:

```
// type the IP and press OK
onView (withId (R.id.dialog_ip_edit_text))
  .check (matches(isDisplayed()))
  .perform (typeText("IP-TO-BE-TYPED"));

onView (withText (R.string.dialog_ok_button_title))
  .check (matches(isDisplayed()))
  .perform (click());

// now, wait for the button and click it
onView (withId (R.id.button))
  .check (matches(isDisplayed()))
  .perform (click());
```

Espresso waits for everything that is happening both in the UI thread and the AsyncTask pool to finish before executing your tests.

Remember that your tests shouldn't do anything that is your application responsability. It should behave like an "well informed user": a user that clicks, verify that something is shown in the screen, but, as a matter of fact, know the IDs of the components

Comment: Your example code is essentially the same code I have written in my question.

Comment: @Binghammer what I mean is the test should behave like the user behaves. Maybe the point I'm missing is what your  IP.enterIP() method does. Can you edit your question and clarify that?

Comment: My comments say what it does. It is just a method in espresso that fills out the IP dialog. It is all UI.

Comment: mm... ok, so you're right, my test is basically doing the same. Do you do something out of the UI thread or AsyncTasks?

Comment: Espresso does not work like the code and text of this answer seems to imply. A check call on a ViewInteraction will not wait till the given Matcher succeeds, but rather fail immediately if the condition is not met. The right way to do this is to either use AsyncTasks, as mentioned in this answer, or, if somehow not possible, implement an IdlingResource that will notify Espresso's UiController on when it is OK to proceed with the test execution.

Comment: @haffax Espresso does not work like that because the application under test is not prepared to do so. With a correct implementation of idling resources this is the only correct answer. The rest are shortcuts that will backfire at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Espresso Idling Resource, it's suggested at this [CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..io2018#5)

> An idling resource represents an asynchronous operation whose results
>   affect subsequent operations in a UI test. By registering idling
>   resources with Espresso, you can validate these asynchronous
>   operations more reliably when testing your app.

Example of an Asynchronous call from the Presenter

```
@Override
public void loadNotes(boolean forceUpdate) {
   mNotesView.setProgressIndicator(true);
   if (forceUpdate) {
       mNotesRepository.refreshData();
   }

   // The network request might be handled in a different thread so make sure Espresso knows
   // that the app is busy until the response is handled.
   EspressoIdlingResource.increment(); // App is busy until further notice

   mNotesRepository.getNotes(new NotesRepository.LoadNotesCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onNotesLoaded(List<Note> notes) {
           EspressoIdlingResource.decrement(); // Set app as idle.
           mNotesView.setProgressIndicator(false);
           mNotesView.showNotes(notes);
       }
   });
}
```

Dependencies

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.1'
```

For androidx

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2'
```

**Official Repo:** https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing

**IdlingResource Example:** https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample

Answer (score 1):

You can also use  CountDownLatch to block the thread, until you receive response from server or timeout.

Countdown latch is a simple yet elegant solution without needing an external library. It also helps your focus on the actual logic to be tested rather than over-engineering the async wait or waiting for a response

```
void testServerAPIResponse() {


        Latch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


        //Do your async job
        Service.doSomething(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(){
                ACTUAL_RESULT = SUCCESS;
                latch.countDown(); // notify the count down latch
                // assertEquals(..
            }

        });

        //Wait for api response async
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertEquals(expectedResult, ACTUAL_RESULT);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think it's best to use Idling Resources for this (https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/) you could probably use this as a fallback:

```
/**
 * Contains view interactions, view actions and view assertions which allow to set a timeout
 * for finding a view and performing an action/view assertion on it.
 * To be used instead of {@link Espresso}'s methods.
 * 
 * @author Piotr Zawadzki
 */
public class TimeoutEspresso {

    private static final int SLEEP_IN_A_LOOP_TIME = 50;

    private static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 10 * 1000L;

    /**
     * Use instead of {@link Espresso#onView(Matcher)}
     * @param timeoutInMillis timeout after which an error is thrown
     * @param viewMatcher view matcher to check for view
     * @return view interaction
     */
    public static TimedViewInteraction onViewWithTimeout(long timeoutInMillis, @NonNull final Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long endTime = startTime + timeoutInMillis;

        do {
            try {
                return new TimedViewInteraction(Espresso.onView(viewMatcher));
            } catch (NoMatchingViewException ex) {
                //ignore
            }

            SystemClock.sleep(SLEEP_IN_A_LOOP_TIME);
        }
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

        // timeout happens
        throw new PerformException.Builder()
                .withCause(new TimeoutException("Timeout occurred when trying to find: " + viewMatcher.toString()))
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Use instead of {@link Espresso#onView(Matcher)}.
     * Same as {@link #onViewWithTimeout(long, Matcher)} but with the default timeout {@link #DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS}.
     * @param viewMatcher view matcher to check for view
     * @return view interaction
     */
    public static TimedViewInteraction onViewWithTimeout(@NonNull final Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {
        return onViewWithTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, viewMatcher);
    }

    /**
     * A wrapper around {@link ViewInteraction} which allows to set timeouts for view actions and assertions.
     */
    public static class TimedViewInteraction {

        private ViewInteraction wrappedViewInteraction;

        public TimedViewInteraction(ViewInteraction wrappedViewInteraction) {
            this.wrappedViewInteraction = wrappedViewInteraction;
        }

        /**
         * @see ViewInteraction#perform(ViewAction...)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction perform(final ViewAction... viewActions) {
            wrappedViewInteraction.perform(viewActions);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * {@link ViewInteraction#perform(ViewAction...)} with a timeout of {@link #DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS}.
         * @see ViewInteraction#perform(ViewAction...)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction performWithTimeout(final ViewAction... viewActions) {
            return performWithTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, viewActions);
        }

        /**
         * {@link ViewInteraction#perform(ViewAction...)} with a timeout.
         * @see ViewInteraction#perform(ViewAction...)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction performWithTimeout(long timeoutInMillis, final ViewAction... viewActions) {
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + timeoutInMillis;

            do {
                try {
                    return perform(viewActions);
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    //ignore
                }

                SystemClock.sleep(SLEEP_IN_A_LOOP_TIME);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException("Timeout occurred when trying to perform view actions: " + viewActions))
                    .build();
        }

        /**
         * @see ViewInteraction#withFailureHandler(FailureHandler)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction withFailureHandler(FailureHandler failureHandler) {
            wrappedViewInteraction.withFailureHandler(failureHandler);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * @see ViewInteraction#inRoot(Matcher)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction inRoot(Matcher<Root> rootMatcher) {
            wrappedViewInteraction.inRoot(rootMatcher);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * @see ViewInteraction#check(ViewAssertion)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction check(final ViewAssertion viewAssert) {
            wrappedViewInteraction.check(viewAssert);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * {@link ViewInteraction#check(ViewAssertion)} with a timeout of {@link #DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS}.
         * @see ViewInteraction#check(ViewAssertion)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction checkWithTimeout(final ViewAssertion viewAssert) {
            return checkWithTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, viewAssert);
        }

        /**
         * {@link ViewInteraction#check(ViewAssertion)} with a timeout.
         * @see ViewInteraction#check(ViewAssertion)
         */
        public TimedViewInteraction checkWithTimeout(long timeoutInMillis, final ViewAssertion viewAssert) {
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + timeoutInMillis;

            do {
                try {
                    return check(viewAssert);
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    //ignore
                }

                SystemClock.sleep(SLEEP_IN_A_LOOP_TIME);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException("Timeout occurred when trying to check: " + viewAssert.toString()))
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it in your code as e.g.:

```
onViewWithTimeout(withId(R.id.button).perform(click());
```

instead of

```
onView(withId(R.id.button).perform(click());
```

This also allows to you to add timeouts for view actions and view assertions.

Comment: Use this below single line of code for dealy any Test Espresso test case:

SystemClock.sleep(1000); // 1 Second

Comment: for me this only works by changing this line `return new TimedViewInteraction(Espresso.onView(viewMatcher));` with `return new TimedViewInteraction(Espresso.onView(viewMatcher).check(matches(isDisplayed())));`

Answer (score -1):

My utility repeats runnable or callable executing until it passes without errors or throws throwable after a timeout.
It works perfectly for Espresso tests!

Suppose the last view interaction (button click) activates some background threads (network, database etc.).
As the result, a new screen should appear and we want to check it in our next step,
but we don't know when the new screen will be ready to be tested.

The recommended approach is to force your app to send messages about threads states to your test.
Sometimes we can use built-in mechanisms like OkHttp3IdlingResource.
In other cases, you should insert code pieces in different places of your app sources (you should known app logic!) for testing support only.
Moreover, we should turn off all your animations (although it's the part of UI).

The other approach is waiting, e.g. SystemClock.sleep(10000). But we don't know how long to wait and even long delays can't guarantee success.
On the other hand, your test will last long.

My approach is to add time condition to view interaction. E.g. we test that new screen should appear during 10000 mc (timeout).
But we don't wait and check it as quickly as we want (e.g. every 100 ms)
Of course, we block test thread such way, but usually, it's just what we need in such cases.

```
Usage:

long timeout=10000;
long matchDelay=100; //(check every 100 ms)
EspressoExecutor myExecutor = new EspressoExecutor<ViewInteraction>(timeout, matchDelay);

ViewInteraction loginButton = onView(withId(R.id.login_btn));
loginButton.perform(click());

myExecutor.callForResult(()->onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title),isDisplayed())));
```

This is my class source:

```
/**
 * Created by alexshr on 02.05.2017.
 */

package com.skb.goodsapp;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

/**
 * The utility repeats runnable or callable executing until it pass without errors or throws throwable after timeout.
 * It works perfectly for Espresso tests.
 * <p>
 * Suppose the last view interaction (button click) activates some background threads (network, database etc.).
 * As the result new screen should appear and we want to check it in our next step,
 * but we don't know when new screen will be ready to be tested.
 * <p>
 * Recommended approach is to force your app to send messages about threads states to your test.
 * Sometimes we can use built-in mechanisms like OkHttp3IdlingResource.
 * In other cases you should insert code pieces in different places of your app sources (you should known app logic!) for testing support only.
 * Moreover, we should turn off all your animations (although it's the part on ui).
 * <p>
 * The other approach is waiting, e.g. SystemClock.sleep(10000). But we don't known how long to wait and even long delays can't guarantee success.
 * On the other hand your test will last long.
 * <p>
 * My approach is to add time condition to view interaction. E.g. we test that new screen should appear during 10000 mc (timeout).
 * But we don't wait and check new screen as quickly as it appears.
 * Of course, we block test thread such way, but usually it's just what we need in such cases.
 * <p>
 * Usage:
 * <p>
 * long timeout=10000;
 * long matchDelay=100; //(check every 100 ms)
 * EspressoExecutor myExecutor = new EspressoExecutor<ViewInteraction>(timeout, matchDelay);
 * <p>
 * ViewInteraction loginButton = onView(withId(R.id.login_btn));
 * loginButton.perform(click());
 * <p>
 * myExecutor.callForResult(()->onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title),isDisplayed())));
 */
public class EspressoExecutor<T> {

    private static String LOG = EspressoExecutor.class.getSimpleName();

    public static long REPEAT_DELAY_DEFAULT = 100;
    public static long BEFORE_DELAY_DEFAULT = 0;

    private long mRepeatDelay;//delay between attempts
    private long mBeforeDelay;//to start attempts after this initial delay only

    private long mTimeout;//timeout for view interaction

    private T mResult;

    /**
     * @param timeout     timeout for view interaction
     * @param repeatDelay - delay between executing attempts
     * @param beforeDelay - to start executing attempts after this delay only
     */

    public EspressoExecutor(long timeout, long repeatDelay, long beforeDelay) {
        mRepeatDelay = repeatDelay;
        mBeforeDelay = beforeDelay;
        mTimeout = timeout;
        Log.d(LOG, "created timeout=" + timeout + " repeatDelay=" + repeatDelay + " beforeDelay=" + beforeDelay);
    }

    public EspressoExecutor(long timeout, long repeatDelay) {
        this(timeout, repeatDelay, BEFORE_DELAY_DEFAULT);
    }

    public EspressoExecutor(long timeout) {
        this(timeout, REPEAT_DELAY_DEFAULT);
    }


    /**
     * call with result
     *
     * @param callable
     * @return callable result
     * or throws RuntimeException (test failure)
     */
    public T call(Callable<T> callable) {
        call(callable, null);
        return mResult;
    }

    /**
     * call without result
     *
     * @param runnable
     * @return void
     * or throws RuntimeException (test failure)
     */
    public void call(Runnable runnable) {
        call(runnable, null);
    }

    private void call(Object obj, Long initialTime) {
        try {
            if (initialTime == null) {
                initialTime = new Date().getTime();
                Log.d(LOG, "sleep delay= " + mBeforeDelay);
                SystemClock.sleep(mBeforeDelay);
            }

            if (obj instanceof Callable) {
                Log.d(LOG, "call callable");
                mResult = ((Callable<T>) obj).call();
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG, "call runnable");
                ((Runnable) obj).run();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            long remain = new Date().getTime() - initialTime;
            Log.d(LOG, "remain time= " + remain);
            if (remain > mTimeout) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG, "sleep delay= " + mRepeatDelay);
                SystemClock.sleep(mRepeatDelay);
                call(obj, initialTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/alexshr/ca90212e49e74eb201fbc976255b47e0

Answer (score -1):

This is a helper I'm using in Kotlin for Android Tests. In my case I'm using the longOperation to mimic the server response but you can tweak it to your purpose.

```
@Test
fun ensureItemDetailIsCalledForRowClicked() {
    onView(withId(R.id.input_text))
        .perform(ViewActions.typeText(""), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard())
    onView(withId(R.id.search_icon)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    longOperation(
        longOperation = { Thread.sleep(1000) },
        callback = {onView(withId(R.id.result_list)).check(isVisible())})
}

private fun longOperation(
    longOperation: ()-> Unit,
    callback: ()-> Unit
){
    Thread{
        longOperation()
        callback()
    }.start()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I will add my way of doing this to the mix:

```
fun suspendUntilSuccess(actionToSucceed: () -> Unit, iteration : Int = 0) {
    try {
        actionToSucceed.invoke()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Thread.sleep(200)
        val incrementedIteration : Int = iteration + 1
        if (incrementedIteration == 25) {
            fail("Failed after waiting for action to succeed for 5 seconds.")
        }
        suspendUntilSuccess(actionToSucceed, incrementedIteration)
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
suspendUntilSuccess({
    checkThat.viewIsVisible(R.id.textView)
})
```

You can add parameters like max iterations, iteration length, etc to the suspendUntilSuccess function.

I still prefer using idling resources, but when the tests are acting up due to slow animations on the device for instance, I use this function and it works well. It can of course hang for up to 5 seconds as it is before failing, so it could increase the execution time of your tests if the action to succeed never succeeds.