# simple JUnit test on Recyclerview in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I'm trying to implement a simple test but my test getting failed. I couldn't see why it's failing

My test case is: Trying to click 5th position in the RecyclerView list. My test code as below.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class RecyclerListActivityTest{

    @Rule @JvmField
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule<RecyclerListActivity>(
        RecyclerListActivity::class.java
    )

    @Test
    fun recyclerTest(){
               onView(withId(R.id.post_list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(5,ViewActions.click()))
    }

}
```

Error:

```
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction@81f0980' on view 'with id: com.kabelash.gitrepos:id/post_list'.
        at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:86)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:87)
        at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:322)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:178)
        at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:119)
```

Note: When I run the app it's works fine without any errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Espresso: PerformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005338/android-espresso-performexception)

Comment: I tried this before posting my question. Anything else I have to check?