# Why does my Android Espresso test fail when I run it?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a bunch of EditTexts, and each one is supposed to focus on the next when something is typed into them. My test checks that this happens:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textBox1)).perform(typeText("1"));
onView(withId(R.id.textBox2)).check(matches(hasFocus()));
```

When I run the app by clicking 'run', it fails saying `hasFocus` wasn't true. Why is this?

Comment: Put `Thread.sleep(200);` before `hasFocus()` line and see what happens.

Comment: Thread.sleep doesn't sleep it and neither does the SystemClock sleep method. I also tried the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563297/4838107 and it didn't work either. Is there a way of making it wait for the actions to finish instead of guessing a time in milliseconds?

Comment: The magic of espresso is, that it waits autimatically, and where there are no more actions to apply - only then matchers are executed. Though, sometimes weird things happen.

Comment: How do I fix this weird thing then?

Comment: @azizbekian It just failed when I ran it without debug now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my SwiftKey keyboard back to the default keyboard on my phone, and now the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced test failures recently using SwiftKey. After switching to GBoard they work. They used to work before with SwiftKey so I think that they changed something recently. I also can see that when using typeText() action SwiftKey automatically corrects words although it has autocorrection disabled.