# Android Espresso wait for text to appear

Tags: android, chatbot, android-espresso

I am trying to automate an Android app that is a chatbot using Espresso. I can say that I am completely new to Android app automation.
Right now I am struggled with waiting. If I use `Thread.sleep`, it works perfectly fine. However, I would like to wait until a specific text appears on the screen. How can I do that?

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

@Test
public void loginActivityTest() {
ViewInteraction loginName = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.text_edit_field),
childAtPosition(childAtPosition(withId(R.id.email_field),0), 1)));
loginName.perform(scrollTo(), replaceText("test@test.test"), closeSoftKeyboard());

ViewInteraction password= onView(allOf(withId(R.id.text_edit_field),
childAtPosition(childAtPosition(withId(R.id.password_field),0), 1)));
password.perform(scrollTo(), replaceText("12345678"), closeSoftKeyboard());

ViewInteraction singInButton = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.sign_in), withText("Sign In"),childAtPosition(childAtPosition(withId(R.id.scrollView), 0),2)));
singInButton .perform(scrollTo(), click());

//Here I need to wait for the text "Hi ..."
```

Some explanations: after pressing the sign in button, the chatbot says "Hi" and gives some more information. I would like to wait for the last one message to appear on the screen.

Answer (score 38):

I like @jeprubio's answer above, however I ran into the same issue @desgraci mentioned in the comments, where their matcher is consistently looking for a view on an old, stale rootview. This happens frequently when trying to have transitions between activities in your test.

My implementation of the traditional "Implicit Wait" pattern lives in the two Kotlin files below.

**EspressoExtensions.kt** contains a function `searchFor` which returns a ViewAction once a match has been found within supplied rootview.

```
class EspressoExtensions {

    companion object {

        /**
         * Perform action of waiting for a certain view within a single root view
         * @param matcher Generic Matcher used to find our view
         */
        fun searchFor(matcher: Matcher<View>): ViewAction {

            return object : ViewAction {

                override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
                    return isRoot()
                }

                override fun getDescription(): String {
                    return "searching for view $matcher in the root view"
                }

                override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {

                    var tries = 0
                    val childViews: Iterable<View> = TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)

                    // Look for the match in the tree of childviews
                    childViews.forEach {
                        tries++
                        if (matcher.matches(it)) {
                            // found the view
                            return
                        }
                    }

                    throw NoMatchingViewException.Builder()
                        .withRootView(view)
                        .withViewMatcher(matcher)
                        .build()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseRobot.kt** calls the `searchFor()` method, checks if a matcher was returned. If no match is returned, it sleeps a tiny bit and then fetches a new root to match on until it has tried X times, then it throws an exception and the test fails. Confused about what a "Robot" is? Check out [this fantastic talk by Jake Wharton](https://academy.realm.io/posts/kau-jake-wharton-testing-robots/) about the Robot pattern. Its very similar to the Page Object Model pattern

```
open class BaseRobot {

    fun doOnView(matcher: Matcher<View>, vararg actions: ViewAction) {
        actions.forEach {
            waitForView(matcher).perform(it)
        }
    }

    fun assertOnView(matcher: Matcher<View>, vararg assertions: ViewAssertion) {
        assertions.forEach {
            waitForView(matcher).check(it)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform action of implicitly waiting for a certain view.
     * This differs from EspressoExtensions.searchFor in that,
     * upon failure to locate an element, it will fetch a new root view
     * in which to traverse searching for our @param match
     *
     * @param viewMatcher ViewMatcher used to find our view
     */
    fun waitForView(
        viewMatcher: Matcher<View>,
        waitMillis: Int = 5000,
        waitMillisPerTry: Long = 100
    ): ViewInteraction {

        // Derive the max tries
        val maxTries = waitMillis / waitMillisPerTry.toInt()

        var tries = 0

        for (i in 0..maxTries)
            try {
                // Track the amount of times we've tried
                tries++

                // Search the root for the view
                onView(isRoot()).perform(searchFor(viewMatcher))

                // If we're here, we found our view. Now return it
                return onView(viewMatcher)

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                if (tries == maxTries) {
                    throw e
                }
                sleep(waitMillisPerTry)
            }

        throw Exception("Error finding a view matching $viewMatcher")
    }
}
```

**To use it**

```
// Click on element withId
BaseRobot().doOnView(withId(R.id.viewIWantToFind), click())

// Assert element withId is displayed
BaseRobot().assertOnView(withId(R.id.viewIWantToFind), matches(isDisplayed()))
```

I know that [IdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource) is what Google preaches to handle asynchronous events in Espresso testing, but it usually requires that you have test specific code (i.e hooks) embedded within your app code in order to synchronize the tests. That seems weird to me, and working on a team with a mature app and multiple developers committing code everyday, it seems like it would be a lot of extra work to retrofit idling resources everywhere in the app just for the sake of tests. Personally, I prefer to keep the app and test code as separate as possible.
/end rant

Comment: Absolutely incredible solution, and some of the nicest code I've seen on this site. Thanks!

Comment: One gotcha with this solution that I discovered is that `matcher.matches(it)` will return true even if the visibility is set to invisible, however the click will fail because it is not visible. Easy solution is just to use `matcher.matches(child).and(child.isVisible)`

Comment: Why not just looping through check(matches(isDisplayed())) instead, catching the NoMatchingViewException exception until the view is displayed? Seems much simpler than this solution.

Comment: @Plgrenier 
the problem is if the ViewMatcher we check fails the first time in the loop, it will always fail no matter how many loops we try, because the ViewHierarchy we check our matches against does not update itself to reflect what’s on the screen. The only way to “refresh” the ViewHierarchy as far as I know, is to force espresso to fetch a new one by creating an entirely new ViewAction to execute the ViewAssertion on ViewMatcher

Comment: onView(withId(someId)).check(matches(isDisplayed())) may fail the first time, throwing a NoMatchingViewException exception, but if you keep trying that check code until the view is visible, this will work. I'm using this strategy on views that only appears after few seconds and it's working just fine once the views are visible, the check passes successfully.

Comment: hmmmm interesting. does this work when you transition between activities? for example, checking for a view in a `HomePageActivity` after you've signed in via a `SignInActivity` ? I ran into the most trouble there; waiting for a view in a new activity.

Comment: Maybe this won't work with your use case. In my case everything happens inside one main activity with multiple fragments. When I have some spare time I will try with multiple activities if my strategy still works :)

Comment: Is there a missing paranthesis on BaseRobot().assertOnView(withId(R.id.viewIWantToFind, matches(isDisplayed())). it should have one right after R.id.viewIWantToFind.  won't compile unless I do but find that it still doesn't work for my deeplinking situation

Comment: You're correct, thank you! I was missing a parenthesis. Updated! 

Care to elaborate on your deep linking situation?

Comment: Did not work for me, I go out to a webview and then when it comes back it fails even with your solution only way I found to come back from webview is         val mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mDevice.pressBack()
but there seems to be a blank screen at some point the this fails on

Answer (score 17):

You can either create an [idling resource](https://medium.com/azimolabs/wait-for-it-idlingresource-and-conditionwatcher-602055f32356) or use a custom [ViewAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/ViewAction.html) as this one:

```
/**
 * Perform action of waiting for a specific view id.
 * @param viewId The id of the view to wait for.
 * @param millis The timeout of until when to wait for.
 */
public static ViewAction waitId(final int viewId, final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for a specific view with id <" + viewId + "> during " + millis + " millis.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + millis;
            final Matcher<View> viewMatcher = withId(viewId);

            do {
                for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    // found view with required ID
                    if (viewMatcher.matches(child)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(waitId(R.id.theIdToWaitFor, 5000));
```

changing `theIdToWaitFor` with the specific id and update the timeout of 5 secs (5000 millis) if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Do you have working examples of Idling resource usage? When I was searching here, all the examples were not working for me.

Comment: I don't. I'm pretty sure this can also be done with idling resources but I still use this `waitId` method for this.

Comment: In my opinion, creating an `idling resource` should be more efficient but the `waitId` approach keeps your code easier to be read and follow. That's why I use the last one.

Comment: @jeprubio this viewAction is interesting, I'm trying to figure out how to use this action. What exactly is `yourViewMatcher` in the code snippet above? Thanks

Comment: I've checked my code and I use it this way: `onView(isRoot()).perform(waitId(R.id.theIdToWaitFor, 5000));`.

Comment: @jeprubio This is amazing stuff. Thank you. Basically I'm testing a firestore app, where the updates are push from the server, so the default sync will not work here, your wait function helps heaps.

Comment: what is the use for isRoot on the onView()? which alternatives do we have?

Comment: isRoot returns a matcher that matches root View. As alternatives, in this case you can match whichever view is in the screen at that moment as the purpose of this matcher is just to wait for some time.

Comment: @jeprubio won't this lead to a stalled root view reference? I mean if after X amount of time, if the target view appears, (let's say a dialog after 2 seconds) you will be iterating trough the view root as it was on the screen when the command was launched, unable to find its target, I just tried and got a view which didn't contain a dialog, then the dialog appeared 3 seconds later, using a delay on my Observable, but it didn't reflected it on  the ViewAction implementation

Comment: Note there are two views here, the one with the id you are waiting for `R.id.theIdToWaitFor` and the other one of the macher which you can forget about it and use the root view. The matcher will finish when a view with that id is visible or the timeout time has expired. Of course it will have some delay this way, if you want no delay you mush create the appropriate idling resource which is more challenging but should work with the minimum delay.

Comment: The problem is not the delay at all, actually it is a fast code, the problem is the view that I can "forget about", the problem with this is that the matcher will never find the view `R.id.theIdToWaitFor` because it was added after the isRoot view is passed, and your ViewAction won't refresh the children of the root.

Comment: To wait until an element is displayed I've just updated few lines to make the `waitDisplayed` from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482891/espresso-test-fails-due-to-timing-issue/58488181

Answer (score 4):

If the text that you're waiting on is in a `TextView` that won't enter the view hierarchy until after the sign-in is complete, then I suggest going with one of the other answers in this thread which operate on the root view (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814995/1071320) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56499223/1071320)).

However, if you're waiting on the text to change in a `TextView` that is already present in the view hierarchy, then I would strongly suggest defining a `ViewAction` that operates on the `TextView` itself for better test output in the case of test failure.

Defining a `ViewAction` that operates on a particular `TextView` instead of operating on the root view is a three-step process as below.

Firstly, define the `ViewAction` class as follows:

```
/**
 * A [ViewAction] that waits up to [timeout] milliseconds for a [View]'s text to change to [text].
 *
 * @param text the text to wait for.
 * @param timeout the length of time in milliseconds to wait for.
 */
class WaitForTextAction(private val text: String,
                        private val timeout: Long) : ViewAction {

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java)
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "wait up to $timeout milliseconds for the view to have text $text"
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout

        do {
            if ((view as? TextView)?.text == text) return
            uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50)
        } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)

        throw PerformException.Builder()
                .withActionDescription(description)
                .withCause(TimeoutException("Waited $timeout milliseconds"))
                .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                .build()
    }
}
```

Secondly, define a helper function that wraps this class as follows:

```
/**
 * @return a [WaitForTextAction] instance created with the given [text] and [timeout] parameters.
 */
fun waitForText(text: String, timeout: Long): ViewAction {
    return WaitForTextAction(text, timeout)
}
```

Thirdly and finally, call on the helper function as follows:

```
onView(withId(R.id.someTextView)).perform(waitForText("Some text", 5000))
```

Comment: This works for me for dynamic text, thank you. In Kotlin you can skip the class creation step if desired and just do `fun waitForText(text: String, timeout: Long): ViewAction = object : ViewAction { /* implement members */ }`