# Android Espresso: Flaky tests due to random ViewNotFoundException

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have a few Espresso tests that fail randomly when trying to click a button.
Sometimes, the tests fail with a ViewNotFoundException.
It appears that the Activity state during this exception is one step behind the expected state.

Note that inserting a Thread.sleep() does *not* solve the issue.

What are possible workarounds to fix those tests?

Comment: Is it possible to get the whole trace ? Is there some network call during when you are planning to click?

Comment: There are network calls, but these network calls do not matter for the button that is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Espresso wait for text to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796132/android-espresso-wait-for-text-to-appear)

Comment: You can set either an `IdlingResource` or the `waitId` method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796132/android-espresso-wait-for-text-to-appear

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are falling behind because of asynchronous tests. Thread.sleep() is not a viable solution, please try to use `IdlingResource` instead : https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource 
Maybe this will help little bit better: https://medium.com/@pedroabinajm/espresso-my-test-is-flaky-28d20cf9b7b7