# Android Espresso UI test - use Idling resource to wait for an element on the screen

Tags: android, android-espresso

I started writing UI tests for `Android` application using `Espresso` framework.
I'm facing an issue that, often, test fails because check that some element is present on the screen happens before that element is displayed. In my case - if I run my test 10 times - 3-4 times it will fail because it won't find an element on the screen

I know that `Google` suggest to use such thing like `idling resources`. But they also suggest to use it in a way of modifying your application code - which is kind of a shitty advice, and I don't want to create spaghetti code by mixing my application code with testing code

So my question - Is it possible to 'force' `espresso` to wait for an element on the screen by using Idling resources?

I was also thinking about creating some helper method with some fluent wait for an element - and then use it like

```
waitForElement(onView(withId(R.id.elementID))
```

so I would really appreciate any advice in this direction.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Espresso wait for text to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796132/android-espresso-wait-for-text-to-appear)

Comment: hey @jeprubio - thanks for your reply. yes I saw that thread too - and for now I've implemented the second answer from that thread which suggests to use Robot pattern. That improved stability of my tests - but still there is about 10% failures because of the same problem - Espresso can't find an element on the screen though it is present

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a custom wait action with both `IdlingResource` and `ViewAction`. The simplest way is to create an `IdlingResource` callback that listens to `ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener` and determines when the app is idling by matching with a `Matcher<View>`:

```
private class ViewPropertyChangeCallback(private val matcher: Matcher<View>, private val view: View) : IdlingResource, ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener {

    private lateinit var callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback
    private var matched = false

    override fun getName() = "View property change callback"

    override fun isIdleNow() = matched

    override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    override fun onDraw() {
        matched = matcher.matches(view)
        callback.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
}
```

Then create a custom `ViewAction` to wait for a match:

```
fun waitUntil(matcher: Matcher<View>): ViewAction = object : ViewAction {

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return any(View::class.java)
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return StringDescription().let {
            matcher.describeTo(it)
            "wait until: $it"
        }
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        if (!matcher.matches(view)) {
            ViewPropertyChangeCallback(matcher, view).run {
                try {
                    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(this)
                    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener(this)
                    uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
                } finally {
                    view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnDrawListener(this)
                    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And perform this action on a root view:

```
fun waitForElement(matcher: Matcher<View>) {
    onView(isRoot()).perform(waitUntil(hasDescendant(matcher))
}

...

waitForElement(allOf(withId(R.id.elementID), isDisplayed()))
```

Or if the view's property can change asynchronously, you can do:

```
onView(withId(R.id.elementID)).perform(waitUntil(withText("textChanged!")))
```

Also, this action may not be suitable for activity transitions.

Comment: Hey @Aaron, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I was not able to make your advice work in my case. Everytime I get `W/IdlingPolicy: These resources are not idle: [View property change callback]` error and then testcase fails because of timeout

Comment: Oh sorry, if you use `onView(isRoot())` then our matcher has to be wrapped in `hasDescendant` in `waitUntil`.